# How to iterate object properties in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have this interface

```
export interface IFilaActividad {
 [key: string]: any
}
```

And I create properties in it dynamically

```
var filaActividad: IFilaActividad = {}

this.columnsToDisplay.forEach(c => {
  Object.defineProperty(filaActividad, c, {});
}
);
```

[image]

I see my properties and now I want to log them

```
for (let prop in filaActividad) {
  console.log("Propiedades", prop);
}
```

But nothing is logged, never pass inside the for

Any idea, please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, properties added using `Object.defineProperty()` are not writable, not enumerable, and not configurable!

When you define a property this way, you can't overwrite it, delete or access via `for...in` or `Object.keys` by default! In order to make it possible to do so, you need to provide additional flags to the third parameter, the data descriptor object.

Insead of

```js
Object.defineProperty(filaActividad, c, {});
```

... you should ...

```js
Object.defineProperty(filaActividad, c, {
    configurable: true,
    writable: true,
    enumerable: true,
    value: undefined
});
```

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)

Answer (score 0):

You don't see anything because all the values within your object are `undefined` (based on the image posted).

If you want to see the `keys` of your object, then just log the `prop`:

```js
for (let prop in filaActividad) {
  console.log("key", prop);
  console.log("the value of that prop: ", filaActividad[prop])
}
```

If you only interested in your object keys, you could also use `Object.keys`:

```js
const myKeys = Object.keys(filaActividad); // string[]

for (const key of myKeys) {
  console.log("key : ", key);
}
```

Comment: It was my mistake when copying the code in the post but it is still that when I try to log only the name of the property, not the value, the code still does not enter the for. Nothing is logged